# Error when using Next.js 14 and next-i18next without locale path and saving locale in cookie

Tags: node.js, next.js, next.js13, i18next

I am trying to implement internationalization in **Next.js 14** by saving the locale in a cookie–without locale paths like /en and /fr. I have encountered an error on client-side pages when the locale differs from the default language: *Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.*

I am using the **next-i18next** plugin, and the [official sample repository](https://github.com/i18next/next-app-dir-i18next-no-locale-path-example) fails with the same error. [Here](https://github.com/i18next/next-app-dir-i18next-example/issues/12) is the discussion that inspired the sample repository.

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.